# HTML Data Attribute with `vaadin-grid`

Tags: html, attributes, polymer, vaadin-grid, dom-repeat

I am trying to get data out of a grid to pass into another element.  I was thinking using HTML data attributes may be a good way to do this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

However, the data attributes don't set and I can't see them in DevTools.

```
<vaadin-grid items="[[data]]">
  <vaadin-grid-column>
    <template class="header">
      <h3>Favorite</h3>
    </template>
    <template>
      <paper-button on-tap="getData"
        data-id="[[item.itemId]]"
        data-desc="[[item.description]]">Go</paper-button>
    </template>
  </vaadin-grid-column>
</vaadin-grid>
```

....

```
getData(e) {
  console.log(e.target.dataset.description);
}
```

**How can I select multiple pieces of data from the table to use in a function?**

For more context: I am trying to get data out of the table and pass as parameters in an AJAX call.

Comment: Maybe a typo? In the log you wrote `description` while setting `data-desc` in `paper-button`. Are you able to log the whole dataset?

Comment: [[item.description]] renders in the DOM when set as `paper-button` text, i.e., `<paper-button>[[item.description]]</paper-button>`.

Comment: I mean: Polymer maps every `data-attrname` to `dataset.attrname` but in your second code block you are logging `e.target.dataset.**description**` while setting `data-**desrc**`. Are you able to see all the data attributes by logging the whole dataset like this: `console.log(e.target.dataset)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the correction of @umbo,

Events use the HTML attribute bindings, and not Polymer element properties.

```
getData(e) {
  console.log(e.target.dataset.desc);
}
```